# Splitting vector of characters in pipe R - keep only the first part of split

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

In my bigger tibble I am trying to split vector of characters in one of the column to get only the first word before a space. I tried to solve in following way:

```
 test <- tibble(ID = c("Monday March", "Tuesday March", "Wednesday March")) %>% 
          mutate(day = strsplit(ID, "\\s")[[1]][1])
```

But I got `Monday` everywhere in my new column:

```
  ID              day   
  <chr>           <chr> 
1 Monday March    Monday
2 Tuesday March   Monday
3 Wednesday March Monday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that dplyr by default uses the whole vector, if you want rowise operations just add rowise, if you prefer to use map I have also provided the answer, honestly I am still torn that the tidyverse is moving away from functional programming, but it is more concise

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(ID = c("Monday March", "Tuesday March", "Wednesday March")) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(day = strsplit(ID, "\\s")[[1]][1]) 


# old school

test <- tibble(ID = c("Monday March", "Tuesday March", "Wednesday March")) %>%
  mutate(day = map_chr(ID,~strsplit(.x, "\\s")[[1]][1]))
```

Comment: As a little note, `rowwise` isn't being actively developed. I think the preferred method these days is the `pmap` function, and equivalents.

Comment: Not really rowise is now the preferred method look into dplyr 1.0.0 post https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/

Comment: Didn't realize Hadley changed his mind with rowwise recently, thanks for the link! There has been so much vascillation over time on its preferred use.

Comment: Yeah I am still not sold as well, so much reading into functional programming :(, I guess not all knowledge is lost, but not it just works @tm which is nice I guess

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut using `separate`. If you don't want to keep the second part of the text you're splitting out, you just don't define a column for it.

```
> test <- tibble(ID = c("Monday March", "Tuesday March", "Wednesday March")) %>% 
+   separate(ID, into='day', remove=F)
Warning message:
Expected 1 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 3 rows [1, 2, 3]. 
> test
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID              day      
  <chr>           <chr>    
1 Monday March    Monday   
2 Tuesday March   Tuesday  
3 Wednesday March Wednesday
```

Comment: `separate` seems purpose built for this and much cleaner.  This should be the accepted answer IMO.